# i want to call a github rest api endpoint from within ado pipelines task

Tags: azure-devops, github-api

i want to call a github rest api endpoint from within ado pipelines task. but its failing with 'bad credentials' error. How can i go about resolving this

```
- task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |  
                  TOKEN=$(var)
                  BRANCH="abc"
                  REPO="xyz"
                  API_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/branches/$BRANCH/protection"
                  
                  response=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "$API_URL")
                            
                  echo "Branch Protection rules"
                  echo "$response"
```

I tried this and expect to get the details on the branch protection. but it gives me 'Bad credentials' error.

I have created a secret inside my repo which sits in GitHub; the $(var) is an ADO pipeline variable and its value is equal to that secret. Can anyone help me here please. thanks

Comment: Did you try to run this locally? From you machine?

Comment: no, i did not do it. not sure how to set my local machine for that.